# Bad system performance (ASRock X299 Taichi + Intel i7 7820-X)

Tags: intel

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Kernel 4.10.0-38-generic
MB: ASRock X299 Taichi
CPU: Intel i7-7820X, no overclocking

This example should produce contiguous sound for 10 seconds, but it breaks several times.

https://pastebin.com/3gptM47z

Compiling:

```
g++ pulsefail.cpp -std=c++11 -lpulse-simple -lpulse
./a.out
```

After adding the following kernel command line options:

```
clocksource=hpet lapic=notscdeadline
```

The sample works as intended. And the overall system performance and responsiveness is much better.

I also tried to measure TSC frequency in this sample using __rdtsc instruction. Before adding kernel options, it calculated to ~3,75 GHz, but after applying the workaround it became ~3,60 GHz.

Notable results of 'dmesg | grep TSC' after changing kernel options:

```
[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST: CPU0: -2477218568993634 force to 0
[    0.183572] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU1: 0
[    0.184601] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU2: 0
[    0.185638] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU3: 0
[    0.186669] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU4: 0
[    0.187698] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU5: 0
[    0.188724] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU6: 0
[    0.189807] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU7: 0
[    0.190802] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU8: 0
[    0.191845] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU9: 0
[    0.192869] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU10: 0
[    0.193901] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU11: 0
[    0.194928] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU12: 0
[    0.195960] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU13: 0
[    0.196986] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU14: 0
[    0.198070] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2477218568993634 CPU15: 0
[   16.499107] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 3600020432 Hz
```

Without them, there isn't much more, except changing clocksource. There are no errors or anything, but TSC frequency is calculated close to 3,75 GHz.

Answer (score 0):

Update: the kernel patch for incorrect TSC frequency issue has been merged. Building a kernel with this patch fixes the issue.

https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10177619/
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/b511203093489eb1829cb4de86e8214752205ac6#diff-96989d5a06fa45e5014d1613838a4f86